# Why do Rangers need to win support of 7 of the other 11 clubs in the SPL?

Tags: football

> Rangers were bought by Charles Green's consortium last week and it has
>   formed a new company that will have to re-apply for SPL membership.
>   But no date has yet been set for the vote, where Rangers need to win
>   support of 7 of the other 11 clubs.

Source: [BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/18476930)

Why do they need 7 votes from the 11 clubs, when 6 would be the majority?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question.

The Scottish Premier League is still technically made up of twelve teams, including the interim "Club 12".

As there are twelve clubs in the league, it is mandated that the majority is 7 and above, although "Club 12" will be a no-vote as it isn't currently certain that the newco Rangers will be that club.

For good reading, here's an [interesting article](http://www.scotsman.com/the-scotsman/sport/football/rangers-takeover-how-spl-clubs-might-vote-on-newco-in-top-flight-1-2351524) on how the other SPL clubs might vote.

Comment: makes sense, automatically assumed club 12 would be the newco and wouldn't vote. so 6 from 11 would be enough. Will be interesting to see how they vote. massive fanbase if it is New Rangers and good income for the league but also a negative that they should be punished fairly.

Comment: It will definitely be interesting.  It could go either way in my opinion.

Comment: And [HERE](http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/18703183) is the outcome.